# Need help Python multiple numbers VAR

Tags: python

I need to make something like this:

```
black = ['1', '3', '5', '7']
white = ['8', '6', '4', '2']
x1 = int(input("type x1"))
x2 = int(input("type x2"))

y1 = int(input("type y1"))
y2 = int(input("type y2"))
if x1 == y1 == black and x2 == y2 == white:
    print("Typed Numbers Is True")
```

How can U make `black` and `white` multiple numbers?
If I type `x1 = 1` and `x2 = 2`
and `y1=1` and `x2= 2` print type me Numbers is true?

Comment: Can you reformulate, it is unclear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this if condition,

```
if (x1 and y1 in black) and (x2 and y2 in white):
    print("Typed Numbers Is True")
```

**Update:**

it's because your list `black` and `white` all the number is string but you take input as int, try to take int in the or remove int in the input section.